# How to use two conditions in one result set set while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, resultset

I need to use two resultset iteration in a single whileloop.

Eg :

```
while(rs1.next() && rs2.next())
{
    if(rs1.next()) 
    { do something } 
    else if(rs2.next()) 
    { do something } 
    else { do something }
}
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: What do you want to do if the result sets are not of the same size?

Comment: have if else conditions. if(rs1.next()) { do something } else if(rs2.next()) { do something } else { do something }

Comment: `while(rs1.next() || rs2.next())` would be a better loop condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the condition that will start while loop is `rs1.next() && rs2.next()` this means if both of them true then start the loop but in loop you have these

```
if(rs1.next()) 
{ do something } 
else if(rs2.next()) 
{ do something } 
else { do something }
```

if you look carefully you can see first condition will always be true(if loop starts of course) and other if statments(or else-if's, else's) will not work. By the way i don't understand what you are looking for clearly, can you explain more?